# Use NLTK without installing

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Learning Python with the Natural Language Toolkit has been great fun, and they work fine on my local machine, though I had to install several packages in order to use it.  Exactly how the NLTK resources are now integrated on my system remains a mystery to me, though it seems clear that the NLTK source code is not simply sitting someplace where the Python interpreter knows to find it.

I would like to use the Toolkit on my website, which is hosted by another company.  Simply uploading the NLTK source code files to my server and telling scripts in the root directory to "import nltk" has not worked; I kind of doubted it would.

What, then, is the difference between whatever the NLTK install routine does and straightforward imports, and why should the toolkit be inaccessible to straightforward imports?  Is there a way to use the NLTK source files without essentially altering my host's Python?

Many thanks for your thoughts and notes.
-G

Answer (score 2):

Not only do you need NLTK on your `PYTHONPATH` (as [@dhg points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166860/4203)), you need whatever dependencies it has; a quick local test indicates that this is really only `PyYAML`. You should just use `pip` to install packages. It's much less error-prone than trying to manually figure out all the dependencies and tweak the `PYTHONPATH` accordingly. If this is a shared host where you don't have the proper access to run a `pip` install, you should ask the host to do it for you.

To address the more general "Whatever the install script is doing" portion of your question: most Python packages are managed using `setup.py`, which is built on top of `distutils` (and sometimes `setuputils`). If this is something you're really interested in, check out [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need system-install support, just the right modules where python can find them. I've set up the NLTK without system install rights with relatively little trouble--but I did have commandline access so I could see what I was doing.

To get this working, you should put together a local install on a computer you *do* control-- ideally one that never had NLTK installed, since you may have forgotten (or not know) what was configured for you. Once you figure out what you need, copy the bundle to the hosting computer. But at that point, check that you're using the module versions that are appropriate for the webserver's architecture. Numpy in particular has different 32/64 bit versions, IIRC.

It's also worth your while to figure out how to see the error messages from the hosting computer. If you can't see them by default, you could catch `ImportError` and display the message it contains, or you could redirect stderr... it depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have the NLTK source located in `/some/dir/`, so that

```
dhg /some/dir/$ ls nltk
...
app
book.py
ccg
chat
chunk
classify
...
```

You can either launch the python interpreter from the directory in which the `nltk` source directory is found:

```
dhg /some/dir/$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
>>> import nltk
```

Or you can add its location to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, which makes NLTK available from anywhere:

```
dhg /whatever/$ export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/some/dir/"
dhg /whatever/$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
>>> import nltk
```

Any other dependencies, including those that NLTK depends on, can also be added to the `PYTHONPATH` in the same way.

Comment: Hi, dhg.  Many thanks for your quick reply, though I guess I wasn't clear.  Scripts on my hosted site in /some/dir/ are unable to import nltk even though the nltk directory and all its contents are also in /some/dir/.  This is why I assumed that something more complicated was being performed when I installed NLTK on my local machine.

Comment: @Gavin, but I think setting the `PYTHONPATH` should work for you.  Did you try that?

Comment: I've added the following line to the script after import sys:  sys.path.append(".../some/dir/"), and this still does not work.  Because I use a hosted account, I have no access to a command line terminal with which to expand Python's paths.  sys.path.append() turned up in a lot of searches for how to expand the path at runtime, and I've tried several variations of sys.path.append(".../some/dir/") such as "/some/dir/nltk", "/some/dir/nltk/", etc.  No luck.  I feel like I must lack some central understanding about how Python expects third party code to be treated.