# Installing nltk without root access

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166819/use-nltk-without-installing) page where answerers have suggested that I can just use nltk on a machine without having root access. I'm trying to follow the advice there but I'm doing something wrong.

I downloaded the source from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (the file named setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz) and then I extracted it to a folder called nltk.

Now from the third answer on that link, I should be able to import nltk by running Python from one of the folders of the extracted contents right?

So I tried running python from the following directories and then importing nltk:

```
~/nltk/
~/nltk/setuptools/
~/nltk/setuptools.egg-info/
~/nltk/setuptools/command/
~/nltk/setuptools/tests/
```

But I can't import the module from anywhere.
I'm a Python rookie. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I actually need to use nltk for a university project and I do not have access root access to the university computers where these projects will run on.

Comment: [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.8.2) is your friend.

Comment: I wish you would elaborate a little

Comment: Have you clicked the link and read what _virtualenv_ does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, from your question it sounds like you're trying to unpack *setuptools* and import *nltk* from it. Those are two totally separate projects.

Secondly, if you want to easily build nltk from source and run it as a normal user, you probably want to start off by using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). On debian you can just install it with `apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

Once virtualenv is installed, you can do

```
virtualenv nltk_env --system-site-packages
```

to create a partially-isolated environment where you can install nltk without messing up your system installation. Then just do

```
source nltk_env/bin/activate
pip install nltk
python
>>> import nltk
```

and you've successfully imported your local nltk installation.

There are other options for installing locally and not using virtualenv, like `pip install --user nltk`, but they can be more confusing if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah I had the wrong archive that I was trying to work with actually. Getting the correct one worked. Thanks anyway.